# Redirect targeting the beginning and end of an old url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Im making redirects of the old pages at the same domain, using htaccess. There are too many urls, and I want to create a general rule to be more practical. How can I create a htaccess rule, that redirects anything that starts with the directory "limitation/" and ends with .html?

Here is my present code, the last line is not ok yet, it does nothing at all. What should I do?

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 ^limitation/(.*).html$ https://example.com/news/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using redirect 301, with some wrong syntax. Here is hat worked:

```
RewriteRule ^limitation/(.+)$ https://nagoyaaqua.jp/news/  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where’s the _“and ends with .html”_ part gone now?